# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'logo' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'logo' in 'field list' (SQL: update `basic_settings` set `footer_text` = We Invest your money property projects and we earn you 40% monthly. Welcome onboard let's join hands together., `copy_text` = Copyright © Pro Invest SA 2017 - 2020 All Right Reserved., `updated_at` = 2020-08-03 23:55:19, `logo` = /tmp/phpfptGnR where `id` = 1)"
```

```
Stacktrace:
#64 Illuminate\Database\QueryException in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
#63 PDOException in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:479
#62 PDO:prepare in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:479
#61 Illuminate\Database\Connection:Illuminate\Database\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657
#60 Illuminate\Database\Connection:runQueryCallback in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
#59 Illuminate\Database\Connection:run in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:490
#58 Illuminate\Database\Connection:affectingStatement in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:423
#57 Illuminate\Database\Connection:update in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2149
#56 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder:update in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:778
#55 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder:update in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:618
#54 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:performUpdate in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:533
#53 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:save in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/app/Http/Controllers/WebSettingController.php:78
#52 App\Http\Controllers\WebSettingController:updateFooter in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#51 call_user_func_array in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#50 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45
#49 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:205
#48 Illuminate\Routing\Route:runController in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:162
#47 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:610
#46 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#45 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
#44 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#43 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#42 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php:43
#41 Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#40 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#39 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:67
#38 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#37 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#36 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#35 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#34 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#33 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:63
#32 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#31 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#30 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#29 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#28 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#27 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:59
#26 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#25 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#24 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
#23 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:612
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:571
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:549
#20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
#19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:56
#17 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
#14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
#11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
#2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in /home/proinve2/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in /home/proinve2/public_html/index.php:55
```

Comment: Please show the table schema for `basic_settings`, it sounds like it doesn't have a `logo` column

Comment: The error telling that, `logo` column doesn't exist on your table `basic_settings`

Comment: Yeah I did and it solved the error. Thank you so much. I am new in this thing hey.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new column to `basic_settings` table using command `php artisan make:migration add_logo_field_to_basic_settings_table`.

Once migration created make Changes like below.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddLogoFieldToBasicSettingsTable extends Migration
{
 
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('basic_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('logo');
        });
    }

   
    public function down()
    {
         Schema::table('basic_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn(['logo']);
        });
    }
}
```

Now you can migrate and create or update `logo` column.

Migrate:
`php artisan migrate`

Comment: As a suggestion, I would recommend to change the `down()` method. As it is, if someone hits `migrate:rollback` then the whole `basic_settings` table would be dropped instead of just dropping the column `logo`

Comment: Thank you for the correction Arun, Updated the code.